# How to create an install-able extension package on local

Tags: ce-1.6.2.0

I am developing a magento extension and testing it, i want to work it something like i upload a zip file from magento connect and it will place my extension files to community folder and global config file to app/etc/module folder and will create db table i have set my DB installer in sql folder but not able to organize the things.

Note : I am developing in localhost

Please help with this,Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your module is called Easylife_Article. This is what you need to be able to run an install sql.
In the config.xml file of the extension you should have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Article>
            <version>0.0.1</version> <!-- this is the module version -->
        </Easylife_Article>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <easylife_article_setup> <!-- this should be the same as the the name of the folder inside the `sql` folder of your extension.
                <setup>
                    <module>Easylife_Article</module>
                </setup>
            </easylife_article_setup>
        </resources>
         ....
    </global>
</config>
```

Now create this file: `app/code/local/Easylife/Article/sql/easylife_article_setup/install-0.0.1.php`. The file name is formed by the work 'install-' and the module version.  If you are building this for versions before 1.6 the file should be named `mysql4-install-0.0.1.php`.
Inside this file you can add your install scripts:

```
$this->startSetup();//start the file with this
$this->run("CREATE TABLE ....");
$this->endSetup();//end the file with this
```

the install script is ran only when installing the extension. To test it multiple times just delete from the table `core_resource` the record with the code the same as the resource name. In the case above `easylife_article_setup`.

Comment: Thanks Marius for your reply, i have all set this but i am looking for how can i get this working? sholud i zip all the files and upload it from magento connect that will install the extension?

Comment: Install it where? If you want to pack the extension and publish it on Magento Connect, use the form found in the menu `System->Magento Connect->Package Extensions`. That will create a zip compliant with Magento Connect. If you want to install it on your local machine you don't need to do that

Comment: Yes i am looking for local install... i have tried all the stuffs but not getting it working :'( i must missing something.

Comment: Actually i am looking it work with Direct package file upload under magento connect.

Comment: Use the packaging extension from Magento. That will create a zip in var/connect folder, that you can install.

Comment: Yup thax a ton... :-)

Comment: [This post over at Mark Shust's blog](http://markshust.com/2012/02/27/packaging-community-extension-distribution-magento-connect) can help decipher all those fields in the packager interface.